# Acumatica Customize Task & Activities pop up

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to customize the Task & Activities pop up screen that shows when you click the Activities button on the top right of most screens in Acumatica?

We have a request to add the task owner field to the list view.

I've tried searching the source code, but I have not been able to figure out how to modify the popup.

I found this in the code, but not sure what page (if any) is linked to this.

```
        [PXUIField(Visible = false, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton(OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh)]
        public virtual IEnumerable ViewAllActivities(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var gr = new ActivitiesMaint();
            gr.Filter.Current.NoteID = ((PXCache<TActivity>)_Graph.Caches[typeof(TActivity)]).InitNewRow().RefNoteID;
            throw new PXPopupRedirectException(gr, string.Empty, true);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which creates the grid and adds column definitions is in:
PX.Web.UI.PXActivityBox class (see full method below).

Unfortunately this can't be changed, it is outside the reach of customization because:

1. The grid is defined in C# source code instead of being declared in an ASPX file.
2. The grid is defined in compiled code which can't be extended, it's not in a graph.

The only workaround I can think of is to create your own action that opens ActivitiesMaint graph (EP405000). This is not the same thing as the ActivityBox and the action would have to be placed outside the main (topmost) toolbar.

```
private void CreateActivityGrid(WebControl div)
{
    var grid = new PXGrid()
    {
        ID = _CONTENT_ID,
        Width = Unit.Percentage(100),
        AllowSearch = true,
        SkinID = "Inquire",
        AllowPaging = true,
        MatrixMode = true
    };
    grid.Levels.Add(new PXGridLevel() { DataMember = "Activity" });
    grid.DataMember = "Activity";
    grid.ActionBar.ActionsText = ActionsTextVisible.True;
    grid.ActionBar.PagerVisible = ActionVisible.False;
    grid.ActionBar.DefaultAction = "cmdViewActivity";
    grid.ActionBar.Position = ActionsPosition.Top;
    grid.CallbackCommands.Refresh.CommitChanges = true;
    grid.CallbackCommands.Refresh.PostData = PostDataMode.Page;
    grid.Mode.AllowAddNew = false;
    grid.Mode.AllowUpdate = false;
    grid.Mode.AllowDelete = false;
    grid.Mode.AllowFormEdit = false;
    grid.Mode.AllowUpload = false;

    grid.AutoSize.Enabled = true;

    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "IsCompleteIcon", Width = Unit.Pixel(21), AllowShowHide = AllowShowHide.False, ForceExport = true });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "PriorityIcon", Width = Unit.Pixel(21), AllowShowHide = AllowShowHide.False, AllowResize = false, ForceExport = true });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "ReminderIcon", Width = Unit.Pixel(21), AllowShowHide = AllowShowHide.False, AllowResize = false, ForceExport = true });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "ClassIcon", Width = Unit.Pixel(31), AllowShowHide = AllowShowHide.False, ForceExport = true });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "ClassInfo", });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "Subject", LinkCommand = "ViewActivity", Width = Unit.Pixel(297), });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "UIStatus" });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "MPStatus" });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "Released", Width = Unit.Pixel(80) });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "StartDate", Width = Unit.Pixel(120), DisplayFormat = "g" });
    grid.Columns.Add(new PXGridColumn() { DataField = "CategoryID" });
    div.Controls.Add(grid);
    grid.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this.Page);
    _content = grid;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks Hugues!

Comment: You can submit a feature request for it on 'feedback.acumatica.com'. You're not the first to ask for this. I understand most customer can't wait for suggestions to be implemented in new versions of Acumatica though.